# How to use @PreAuthorize with dynamic user roles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a project, where I have user roles, based on their language.

For example, I have `MODERATOR` roles, which are set based on what languages they speak, for example, `MODERATOR_en_GB`, or `MODERATOR_en_US`.

On a given API end-point I would like to check whether the user has the `MODERATOR_language_REGION` role - the `language_REGION` comes as a parameter on that end-point.

But I don't know how to use the `@PreAuthorize(hasAnyRole)` function, with this kind of dynamic role.

My `MODERATOR` enum looks like this:

```
        public static enum MODERATOR {
            en_US("ROLE_MODERATOR_en_US"),
            en_GB("ROLE_MODERATOR_en_GB");

            private final String role;

            MODERATOR(String role) {
                this.role = role;
            }

            public String getRole() {
                return role;
            }
        };
```

Then, I have my API endpoint like so:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('" + MODERATOR + "', '" + ADMIN + "')")
@GetMapping("/edit")
public List<PostsDto> getPostsForEdit(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "en_GB") Language language,
                               @PageableDefault(sort = "skippedCount") Pageable pageable) {
    ... some code
}
```

Obviously, this does not work, since `MODERATOR` is an enum.

So I tried to do something like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(MODERATOR.valueOf(#language), '" + ADMIN + "')")
```

What I did here, was to try and use the `language` parameter from the API end-point on the `@PreAuthorize(hasAnyRole)` function.

In the same way, they use the `#foo` in the example from here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression#3-example-in-practice

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a bean with a method that returns a `boolean` that does the check you need. Then call this method in the `@PreAuthorize`. Something like `@PreAuthorize(@bean.yourMethod)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using SpeL you can invoke a bean and pass the parameters to the bean method, you could pass the `locale` and the `Authentication` objects, as well as the expected role.

```java
@Service
public class AuthorizationService {

    public boolean hasRoleLocale(String locale, Authentication authentication, String expectedRole) {
        authentication.getAuthorities(); // Use to check the authorities/roles
        expectedRole + request.getLocale() // Use the locale from the request
        // Do the business requirement for the authorization
    }

}
```

And, in your Controller, you can do like:

```java
@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.hasRoleLocale(locale, authentication, 'MODERATOR')")
```

Answer (score -2):

Do you have MethodSecurity enabled?

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = 
          new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: Enabling it won't automatically make it magicaly work for dynamic role names. The latter is what the question is about, not about enabling the annotation.

Comment: Sure but it needs to be enabled to work in the first place

Comment: Which is explicitly what the question isn't about.